# springcloud cannot regonize the uri

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I am going to use the web client to call api from other microservice.However, the web client cannot regconzied my url and give the error.

```
2023-01-23T17:10:17.261+08:00 ERROR 114017 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request from UNKNOWN ] with root cause

org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request from UNKNOWN 
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException.create(WebClientResponseException.java:309) ~[spring-webflux-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ 400 BAD_REQUEST from GET http:/localhost:8082/Checkuser/252 [DefaultWebClient]
Original Stack Trace:
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException.create(WebClientResponseException.java:309) ~[spring-webflux-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultClientResponse.lambda$createException$1(DefaultClientResponse.java:213) ~[spring-webflux-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:106) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorReturn$ReturnSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorReturn.java:162) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:122) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:299) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:337) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$BaseFluxToMonoOperator.completePossiblyEmpty(Operators.java:2071) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollect.java:145) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
        at
```

My code:

```
 Boolean result=webClientBuilder.build().get()
                .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
                        .path("http://localhost:8082/Checkuser/{id}")//"http://localhost:8082/Checkuser/{id}")
                        .build(252))
                        .retrieve()
                                .bodyToMono(Boolean.class)
                                        .block(); //make syn request

        if(Boolean.FALSE.equals(result)){
           throw new IllegalAccessException("User score to low");
```

My config file:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalanced;

@Configuration
public class webclientconfig {
    @Bean
    public WebClient webClient(){
        return WebClient.builder().build();
    }
    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public WebClient.Builder loadBalancedWebClientBuilder(){
        return WebClient.builder();
    }
}
```

The webclient automatically ignore my "/" after http which i have typed

Comment: The client code is correct. It's calling service and the service is returning a 400. The problem might be in the service and/or that the request is incorrect.

Comment: Unluckily,The uri give a correct result in postman